# Linker Error - class doesn't exist anymore

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, linker

Getting the following linker error, in XCode and my project won't build.
Problem is, the class doesnt exist anymore. I had a class named `SomeOtherViewController` but then deleted it. When I try and build its somehow still looking for it.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SomeOtherViewController", referenced from:
```

How can I solve this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clean your builds.
2. Build again.

To clean do one of following:

1. Product -> Clean
2. Shift + CMD + K